# Xcode Find and replace in all project files

Tags: macos, xcode5

I need to replace `NSLog` with `DDLogVerbose` in all files in the current project I am working on… What is an easy method to do this? (the search navigator only has search in it).

Also I need to add a line at the beginning of all .m files. How is this done quickly? (There are over 500 such files.)

Comment: I'm sure you can do this with cmd-shift-f and then selecting the replace mode?

Comment: Click on 'Find' (in the search navigator) and choose 'Replace' from the dropdown.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Here are some pictures. In the toolbar search, you have to press 'Find' then a menu appears – pick replace. Now you can replace project-wide.

[image: step 1]
[image: step 2]

Comment: I felt a bit silly when this wasn't working for me, but I found that after typing in the source of the replace I had to press enter for XCode to actually search through to find the matching strings.  Otherwise the Replace / Replace All buttons remained disabled.

Comment: Thanks Tim - that MUST be a bug - I was trying to figure out why the search/replace button was still greyed out.

Comment: are there shortcuts? `⌘3` opens find and search but can I also switch between find and replace?

Comment: Wow that UX :'(